# Very slow query on wordpress caused by meta query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to add in a slideshow 2 types of slides based on 2 different keys, just that the meta query is extremely slow. The wordpress query that I am using is:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'sgt_slide',
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'sgt_slide_home',
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'no_found_rows' => true, //exclude unnecessary paging calculations
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'inherit' ),
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'attachment' )
    );
$slides = get_posts($args);
```

and the sql matching query that results is

```
SELECT   nd_posts.* FROM nd_posts  INNER JOIN nd_postmeta ON (nd_posts.ID = nd_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN nd_postmeta AS mt1 ON (nd_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND nd_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'attachment') AND ((nd_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR nd_posts.post_status = 'inherit')) AND ( (nd_postmeta.meta_key = 'sgt_slide' AND CAST(nd_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'on')
OR  (mt1.meta_key = 'sgt_slide_home' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'on') ) GROUP BY nd_posts.ID ORDER BY nd_posts.post_date DESC
```

This sql resulted query loads in 7 seconds, tested in phpmyadmin. How can I overcome this.

EXPLAIN SQL

[image: explain sql]

Comment: Do you have try "explain" sql ?

Comment: you need to add an index on `post_type` something as `alter table nd_posts add index post_type_idx(post_type)`

Comment: Advice: in order to see where the bottle neck of the query is, start to disable one by one the components of the `$args`

Comment: Ok, I have resarched some more and it seams that the `relation => OR` is the issue. But how to solve it for my case. I need to have `get_posts` function.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Tried adding the index on that and still same timing.

Comment: I highly doubt database would have problem with condition relations. This is a clear case of missing indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok fond how to solve it based on this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158898/meta-query-terribly-slow

```
function wpse158898_posts_clauses( $pieces, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $relation = isset( $query->meta_query->relation ) ? $query->meta_query->relation : 'AND';
    if ( $relation != 'OR' ) return $pieces; // Only makes sense if OR.
    $prepare_args = array();
    $key_value_compares = array();
    foreach ( $query->meta_query->queries as $meta_query ) {
        // Doesn't work for IN, NOT IN, BETWEEN, NOT BETWEEN, NOT EXISTS.
        if ( ! isset( $meta_query['value'] ) || is_array( $meta_query['value'] ) ) return $pieces; // Bail if no value or is array.
        $key_value_compares[] = '(pm.meta_key = %s AND pm.meta_value ' . $meta_query['compare'] . ' %s)';
        $prepare_args[] = $meta_query['key'];
        $prepare_args[] = $meta_query['value'];
    }
    $sql = ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' pm on pm.post_id = ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID'
        . ' AND (' . implode( ' ' . $relation . ' ', $key_value_compares ) . ')';
    array_unshift( $prepare_args, $sql );
    $pieces['join'] = call_user_func_array( array( $wpdb, 'prepare' ), $prepare_args );
    $pieces['where'] = preg_replace( '/ AND[^' . $wpdb->postmeta[0] . ']+' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.*$/s', '', $pieces['where'] ); // Zap postmeta clauses.
    return $pieces;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse158898_posts_clauses', 10, 2 );
$slidess = new WP_Query($args);
$slides = $slidess->get_posts();
remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse158898_posts_clauses', 10 );
```

And managed to imitate same pattern of `get_posts` with new `WP_query` and `get_posts()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add 
`'cache_results' => false,`
to your loop

Comment: It improved it with one second, from 7 seconds to 6 seconds loading. But I needed to get it improved to less than 1 seconds, from my research the issue resides in the `meta_query` => `relation` sub-array element.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress casts to char() which stops the index being used. The following code uses a filter to remove the cast:

```
/**
 * Remove casting a meta_query to a char as this stops it using the index!
 */

function my_filter_meta_query( $pieces ) {
 if ( !empty( $pieces['where'] ) ) {
     // remove casting to CHAR as this is already a string
     $pieces['where'] = preg_replace("@CAST\(([^.]*.meta_value) AS CHAR\)@", "$1",$pieces['where']);
 }
return $pieces;
}

add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'my_filter_meta_query' );
```

More details http://www.topsemtips.com/2015/01/wordpress-meta-query-slow-wp_query/